# Does Themeroller no longer support ui-checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[**I downloaded the latest jQuery UI from their Themeroller site**](http://jqueryui.com/download) wanting to implement ui-checkboxes and cannot "seem" to find any reference or examples for it any longer.

- [**Here is an online example of what I was hoping to implement**](http://www.openpave.org/~reg/jqueryui-checkbox.html)
- [**This is all I have found to be available**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox) (...and I hate this)

**Did it go away?**
**And if so, why?**

The version is I downloaded was jquery-ui-1.8.16 (I downloaded the entire thing).  I searched all the CSS files with no mention of the tag `ui-checkbox`.

...it just struck me as odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's part of the official jquery-ui package. Is it [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/8827/release) plugin?

Comment: Thank you.  That is so odd!  I would think it would be part of their whole UI implementation.  Especially, since it uses the same vernacular.

Answer (score 1):

According to that I have found, that particular plugin was broken past the 1.7.2 version of jquery, so it is broken.  However, someone did make a version (not sure how compatible it is with the newest versions) that is compatible with 1.8.5.  That can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryuicheckbox/)